# Is there a way to make an infinite loop in python?

Tags: python, loops

I know you can just do this (technically):

```
import time
variable = 0 
while variable < 99999999999999999999999999999999999999
  variable = variable + 1
  time.sleep(1)
```

But is there just a way to make an infinite loop without typing all those 9's?
(idk if this makes sense but I'm sure you get what I mean)

Comment: `while True:` ?

Comment: All you need is a condition that will *always* be true.  `1 == 1` will always be true.  `True` will always be true.  Etc.  Your `variable < 99999999999999999999999999999999999999` condition will also always be true if you don't increment `variable` 99999999999999999999999999999999999999 times.

Comment: You can also use a `for` loop, you just need an infinite iterable. There are a few of those in the Python standard library, like `itertools.count`, which counts up like the `variable` in your question: `for variable in itertools.count():` will count up forever, just in case you actually need that.

Comment: @Blckknght `iter(int, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Because you want an infinite loop with a one-second delay between iterations.